# Function call always returns 0

Tags: solidity, truffle

Working with a simple contract to get the hang of this. I can't seem to get the correct value back from my contract function. It always outputs 0.

Truffle version: 4.1.15

Contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract HelloWorld {
    uint public balance;

    constructor() public {
        balance = 1000;
    }

    function deposit(uint _value) constant public returns (uint _newValue) {
        balance += _value;
        return balance;
    }

    function get() constant public returns (uint) {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Truffle commands:

```
const hw = HelloWorld.at("0x90BB90BA04612eb9B30A2640BC7516168A684cE7");
undefined
hw.deposit(500).then(function(balance){n = balance.toNumber(10); console.log(n);})
0
undefined
hw.get().then(function(balance){n = balance.toNumber(10); console.log(n);})
0
undefined
```

Both `deposit()` and `get()` seem to return 0 no matter what. This should at least return the initial value of `balance` (1000), right?

Comment: You're probably going too fast and the transaction isn't mined. When scripting this sort of thing it's important to wait for confirmation of the transaction before pressing on.

Comment: Shouldn't this still return 1000 (the default value) at least? @RobHitchensB9lab

Comment: On closer look, yes it should. Try toString (10) instead of toNumber.

Comment: No dice. Still returns 0, but as a string (text is a slightly different color than integers in console). @RobHitchensB9lab

Comment: truffle version?

Comment: @Aniket 4.1.15. Had to roll back from 5 in order for solc to deploy contracts without errors.